# How to remove an Item from a list?

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have this model:

```
public class StationData
{
    public int StationID{ get; set; }
    public List<int> FileID { get; set; }
}
```

In my main page, I call a method that will return an object of type "StationData".

Now, what I want is to remove an item from the "List" where FileID = value;

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var tempItem = data.FirstOrDefault(item => item.FileID.Any(field => field == 1));
        if (tempItem != null)
            data.Remove(tempItem);
```

O, sorry i misunderstood

```
StationData data = new StationData();
var tempItem = data.FileID.Where(item => item == value);
if(tempItem !=null)
{
            var enumerable = tempItem.ToList();
            foreach (var i in enumerable)
            {
                data.FileID.Remove(i);
            }
}
```

Comment: This works, but somehow if I have more than 1 data in my List<int> FileID, all of those list data is being returned.  SO the moment the code data.remove(tempItem) is being executed.  all of the data are being deleted.

Comment: got an error, this line of code " data.FileID. " generates an error... "Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CS250Project.Model.ServerDataModel>' does not contain a definition for 'FileID' and no extension method 'FileID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CS250Project.Model.ServerDataModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"